# How to compress files in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form which sends 2 images to my controller

```
 <form action="generate" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image1" size="20" /> 
    <input type="file" name="image2" size="20" /> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Now in my controller i want to compress `image1` and `image2` to zip format and save it in a folder.
I also see this [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html) but i don't know how to add 2 images in one file .

Any ideas?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter has a library meant for helping with zip utilities:

You can load it like this:

```
$this->load->library('zip');
```

Then the class object can be accessed as:

```
$this->zip
```

For zipping a file, you can do this:

```
$path1 = '/path/to/photo1.jpg';  
$path2 = '/path/to/photo2.jpg';    
$this->zip->read_file($path1); 
$this->zip->read_file($path2); 
$this->zip->archive('/path/to/folder/my_images.zip');
```

You can read more at [CodeIgniter's Zip Library Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html)

Comment: I want to add to `$_FILES['image1']` and `$_FILES['image2']` to `add_data`

Comment: You can use `read_file()` for that. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Should i change `$path1` to `$_FILES['image1']`

Comment: You have to provide the path to where the images it. The $_FILES array has that information in one of its indices

Comment: this is my Array `Array ( [image1] => Array ( [name] => temp1.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/php8hwoG1 [error] => 0 [size] => 6342 ) ` should i pass `$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']` ?